# Thread map to 2 lists of inputs, including the nondiagonal terms

Tags: list-manipulation, mapthread

Given a function f and two lists of variables

```
{a1,a2,...}, {b1,b2,...}
```

How can I generate a following list

```
{f[a1,b1],f[a1,b2],...,f[a2,b1],f[a2,b2]...,}
```

==========================================

Thanks for the answering of @Bill first.
I am not familiar with the function "Mapthread". The best thing I can do is as following

```
Mapthread[f,{l1,l2}]
```

leading to a list

```
{f[a1,b1],f[a2,b2],...}
```

There is no f[a1,b2] in this result. How can I get a full list that I want?

Comment: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapThread.html

Comment: I have considered the mapthread, but I didn't manage it. Could u show me the more details?

Comment: "I have considered the mapthread, but I didn't manage it." In such cases, please always show what you have tried. Show a minimal working example that illustrates your problem (i.e. shows what went wrong).

Comment: Frankly, the `MapThread` documentation contains everything anyone could write in an answer here. Voting to close as "simple to find in the documentation".

Comment: `MapThread[f,{{...},{...}}]`

Comment: `a = {a1, a2, a3};`  `b = {b1, b2, b3};` `MapThread[f, {a, b}]` gives `{f[a1, b1], f[a2, b2], f[a3, b3]}` and then EDIT: the question got changed.

Comment: The numbers of elements are different. And I hope to get the "nondiagnonal" terms such as f[a1,b2].

Comment: and then EDIT: ... non diagonal terms ...

Comment: @user1066 it does work. But why? What's the meaning of the triple "List" respectively?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Now it's clearer. Voted to reopen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Originally you were asking:

```
a = {a1, a2, a3};
b = {b1, b2, b3};
MapThread[f, {a, b}]
```

> {f[a1, b1], f[a2, b2], f[a3, b3]}

> How can I get a full list that I want?

What you are now looking for is called an outer product.

```
Flatten[Outer[List, a, b], 1]
```

> ```
> {{a1, b1}, {a1, b2}, {a1, b3}, {a2, b1}, {a2, b2}, {a2, b3}, {a3, 
>   b1}, {a3, b2}, {a3, b3}}
> ```

```
f @@@ Flatten[Outer[List, a, b], 1]
```

> ```
> {f[a1, b1], f[a1, b2], f[a1, b3], f[a2, b1], f[a2, b2], f[a2, b3], 
>  f[a3, b1], f[a3, b2], f[a3, b3]}
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is just the problem at beginning.

Comment: @RuiYu This is not the proper way to ask a question. You cannot change your question every 2 minutes. Please return to the forum when you have formed the question.

Comment: Thanks. I did not change my question. Maybe at beginning it is a little misleading. I will be more cautious next time. By the way, how to close a question?

Comment: Users with "Close" vote privileges can close your questions. It's okay, no one minds helping you out, but it is in your interest to ask well-formed stable and non-trivial  questions, otherwise responders will have lesser motivation to answer them.

Comment: `Flatten@Outer[f, a, b]`

Comment: @LouisB : Of course. Learned it. My functional thinking is still weak  and I am learning, so I appreciate your feedback. In this case, the query changed and this seemed like a natural way to show the progression.

Answer (score 5):

```
a = {a1, a2, a3};
b = {b1, b2, b3};

f @@@ Tuples[{a, b}]
(*    {f[a1, b1], f[a1, b2], f[a1, b3],
       f[a2, b1], f[a2, b2], f[a2, b3],
       f[a3, b1], f[a3, b2], f[a3, b3]}    *)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
a = {a1, a2, a3}; b = {b1, b2, b3};

Tuples[f[a, b]]
```

> ```
> {f[a1, b1], f[a1, b2], f[a1, b3], 
>  f[a2, b1], f[a2, b2], f[a2, b3], 
>  f[a3, b1], f[a3, b2], f[a3, b3]}
> ```

Also

```
Distribute[f[a, b], List]
```

> ```
> {f[a1, b1], f[a1, b2], f[a1, b3], 
>  f[a2, b1], f[a2, b2], f[a2, b3], 
>  f[a3, b1], f[a3, b2], f[a3, b3]}
> ```